# I'm building a website with rubyonrails and the destroy function is not working instead it is invoking the show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the destroy function

```
 def destroy

@restaurant.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
  end
```

Comment: Post the contents of your `routes.rb` file as well as the `erb` code where you invoke `destroy`.

Comment: Are you requiring jquery_ujs in your application.js?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is being built following standard Rails conventions: check that in your view, you include **method: 'delete'** in link_to parameters. See below:

```
<%= link_to "destroy", restaurant, method: 'delete' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

just like on the answer above when you call the function destroy on you view be sure to have

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Restaurant', (****), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

let's assume you have a list of restaurants and you want the destroy option on your loop to delete a **certain** , then you would need to replace *** for whatever is in your loop

```
<% @restaunrants.each do |restaunrant| %>
```

in this case would be with "restaunrant"

IF for some reason you are showing only one restaurant and you want to delete exacly this one you would replace it for @restaurant ( which wouldn't make that much sence.. but it depends on your code)

you can also send a "fancy" message using the extra

```
, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```